# GridView, Picasso Not Loading Into ImageView

Tags: java, android, gridview, picasso

I can't load image into `ImageView` using `Picasso`. I searched so much but I couldn't find answer.

There is a `GridView` and GridView has an `ImageView` and `TextView`. I used Picasso to load image into ImageView.

Here is adapter:

```
public class MyGridAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
Context context;
LayoutInflater inflater;
public List<Photo> data ;
Photo photo = new Photo();

public MyGridAdapter(Context context,
                     List<Photo> arraylist) {
    this.context = context;
    data = arraylist;
    //imageLoader = new ImageLoader(context);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return data.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // Declare Variables
    TextView phototitle;
    ImageView imageView;

    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gridview_item, parent, false);
    // Get the position
    photo = data.get(position);

    phototitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.phototitle);
    imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);


    phototitle.setText(photo.getTitle());

    String url = photo.getUrl();
    Log.d("url", url);
    Picasso.with(context).setLoggingEnabled(true);
    Picasso.with(context).load(url).into(imageView);

    return itemView;
}
}
```

Here is GridView item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/phototitle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="10sp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

output:

```
 12-23 22:03:03.921 18840-18840/com.mehmetsefa.challenge D/url: http://placehold.it/150/bb7f4
12-23 22:03:03.926 18840-18840/com.mehmetsefa.challenge W/Settings: Setting airplane_mode_on has moved from android.provider.Settings.System to android.provider.Settings.Global, returning read-only value.
12-23 22:03:03.931 18840-18840/com.mehmetsefa.challenge D/Picasso: Main        created      [R0] Request{http://placehold.it/150/bb7f4}
12-23 22:03:03.936 18840-19224/com.mehmetsefa.challenge D/Picasso: Dispatcher  enqueued     [R0]+2ms 
12-23 22:03:03.936 18840-19226/com.mehmetsefa.challenge D/Picasso: Hunter      executing    [R0]+2ms 
12-23 22:03:03.946 18840-18840/com.mehmetsefa.challenge D/url: http://placehold.it/150/bb7f4
```

What do I wrong?

Comment: is output fro this  Log.d("url", url);

Comment: I added output.

Comment: try adding Picasso.with(Context).setLoggingEnabled(true); which will give logs about any picasso related problems...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do nothing wrong, your images are wrong. I guess it is because it has no extension or is formed not immediately after request is shot. Your image is being formed with some kind of CG library and it generates image just after request completion, so body is returned empty.

Comment: What do you suggest?

Comment: Switch to normal images, not generated on the fly. Or try another library, maybe Glide will deal better.

Answer (score 0):

You are mostly missing the INTERNET permission. When you are trying to debug Picasso here is what I suggest:

Create a Builder like this:

```
Picasso.Builder builder = new Picasso.Builder(context);
        builder.listener(new Picasso.Listener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onImageLoadFailed(Picasso picasso, Uri uri, Exception exception)
            {
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        picasso = builder.build();
```

use the above instance to load the image:

```
picasso.load(url).into(imageView);
```

You will see in the log if there are any errors. Good luck.

Comment: It was not the internet permission. I used Glide instead of Picasso/

Comment: Hi @MehmetSefaBalık did you try using the Picasso Builder as suggested. What is the exception you are seeing?

Comment: Hey @MehmetSefaBalık I know you have moved on to Glide which is what I like more than Picasso ;). But here is the working implementation. https://github.com/write2sv/GridViewPicasso